# Currency symbol ₹ (Indian Rupee) not displayed in Mozilla

Tags: javascript, html

The Indian Rupee symbol is not displayed on Firefox 35.0 with Windows 7 and Windows XP. I have used the following symbol "₹", taken from the following link http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/20b9/index.html

It shows an empty square instead of the symbol.

Comment: Are you using a particular font ?
What is the charset you use ?

Comment: What is present in the HTML code? The ₹ symbol or for example &#8377; ?

Comment: Character set UTF-8 @Heru-Luin

Comment: the symbol (₹) is present in the HTML code @MeanGreen

Answer (score 1):

Use a span tag and change the font-family to something like this:

```
<span style="font-family: DejaVu Sans;">&#x20b9;</span>
```

Answer (score 1):

Replace the symbol with either `&#8377;` or `&#x20b9;`. This helps with charset problems.

Comment: Not from my experience. Where € fails the code &euro; did work.